# Autostart with full admin privileges for a standard user in Windows 10

Tags: windows, boot, administrator, uac, autostart

I want to run a program with administrative rights (using the administrator account that I control) at startup on a Windows 10 machine, for a standard account user.

That means that the usual way, using the task scheduler to set the program to run with highest privileges as the administrator user on any user's login, does not work; the program simply does not start.

One user has already asked a similar question, but the accepted [answer](https://superuser.com/a/860874/428353) requires me to save the administrator account's password in clear text somewhere, if I understand correctly.

Is there any way to get this to work without any such security holes?

Comment: My preferred solution in cases like this is to grant the standard user the necessary permissions to run the program with their own account. Usually this is NTFS permissions to the program's folders and permissions to keys modified by the program in the registry. Process Monitor from SysInternals/Microsoft is useful for determining exactly what permissions should be granted.